# Compressing a dir of individually compressed files vs. recompressing all files together

Tags: compression

I have a directory of ZIP-compressed webpages (.maff), each webpage compressed separately. Some of these webpages are variants of the same page and are only slightly different from each other - say, 10% different. I want to compress the entire folder (hundreds of files) into a single archive.

Theoretically, compressing many identical (10% variance) files should be very efficient (~90%).

But I'm wondering: how efficient is secondary compression of **individually compressed** slightly different files? At least, theoretically?

What compression algorithm loses the least of its strength when applied in such a two-stage way?

Maybe, one should use different algorithms for first and second stage to maximize the overall compression? (In my case, however, first algorithm is fixed by MAFF standard to be a ZIP compression).

Comment: Compressing already compressed files is likely to be unrewarding.

Comment: Not unrewarding in the case of many similar files. Currently, secondary compression gives me additional 3x compression ratio.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1166385/56778