# Is it possible to compress a piece of already-compressed-data by encrypting or encoding it?

Tags: encoding, compression

Many compression algorithms take advantage of the fact that there's redundancy/patterns in data. `aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccc` could be compressed to `10'a'11'b'12'c'`, for example.

But that there's no more redundancy in my compressed data, I couldn't really compress it further. However, I *can* encrypt or encode it and turn it into a different string of bytes: `xyzxyzxyzxyzxyz`.

If the random bits *just so happened* to have a pattern in them, it seems that it'd be easy to take advantage of that: `5'xyz'`

Here's what our flow looks like:

```
Original:         aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccc
Compressed:       10'a'11'b'12'c'
Encrypted:        xyzxyzxyzxyzxyz
Compressed again: 5'xyz'
```

But the more data you have, the larger your file, the more effective many forms of encryption will be. Huffman encoding, especially, seems like it'd work really well on random bits of data, especially when the file gets pretty large!!

I imagine this would be atrocious when you need data fast, but I think it could have merits for storing archives, or other stuff like that. Maybe downloading a movie over a network would only take 1MB of bandwidth instead of 4MB. Then, you could unpack the movie as the download happened, getting the full 4MB file on your hard drive without destroying your network's bandwidth.

So I have a few questions:

1. Do people ever encode data so it can be compressed better?
2. Do people ever "double-compress" their data?
3. Are there any well-known examples of "double" compression, where data is compressed, encrypted or encoded, then compressed again?

Comment: Why do you think Huffman encoding would be efficient for random data? It relies on the probability of some pieces of data occurring being different than the probability of other pieces of data occurring. That won't be the case for large pieces of truly random data.

Comment: You're right, if the data is truly random, Huffman encoding wouldn't work at all. Here's my logic. Compression takes advantage of patterns in data, rendering it pattern-less. Encryption scrambles data, and since we're already pattern-less there're only the possibilities or remaining pattern-less, or introducing some pattern to the data.

Comment: @EdmCoff I was confused: Once huffman-encoded, a message kinda looks like a string of random bits. But a string of random bits isn't efficient to huffman-encode. Worst-case, huffman encoding doesn't add any bits to the message (other than the header-table, is that large enough of an overhead to be relevant?). I suppose I find it tough to believe that EVERY time you encrypt/encode compressed data with EVERY algorithm, you'll be unable to find a pattern that you can exploit to compress with ANY compression algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good encryption results in high-quality random data, so it can not be compressed. The probability of a compressible result "just so happened" from an encryption is the same as it would be from any other random data source. Which is simply never.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense for encryption. But .tar.gz's got me thinking about all of this, so that's why I included encryption. I suppose I should change my question to only mention encoding. So, encryption by definition won't help with this. But what about encoding? There's an infinite number of functions you can use to encode data, thus by the Pigeon Hole Principle, one method of encoding would HAVE to reduce the randomness (and increase the compress-ability) of your data, right? The only problem is... how expensive would it be to find that right encoding function.

Comment: No. The problem is how many bits will it take to describe the encoding function. That has to be transmitted along with the data. Those bits will put you right back where you started.

Comment: That's something that I was worried about, but if the file was REALLY really large, then my thoughts were that the fixed overhead (10s of Kilobytes, per compression) would hopefully be offset. Another issue with compressing like this is that you'd really have to "mine" to find a good encoding function... if you could measure a loss function based on how unpatterned the data is this would be an easier problem.. But uncompressing and decoding would be relatively cheap. This would really only be useful for mass distribution of large files to clients. Maybe something like Netflix could use this?

Comment: There is nothing useful to use. This is a not a problem of how long it takes to find something. Even with infinitely fast and powerful computers, there is nothing that can be found to enable the compression of random data.

Answer (score 1):

Double compression is like perpetual motion. It is a oft discussed idea but never works. If it worked, you could compress and compress and compress and get the file down to 1 bit... See 
[How many times can a file be compressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166385/how-many-times-can-a-file-be-compressed)

The fundamental problem is that most files are NOT compressible--random, encrypted files even less so.

To answer your questions:

1) yes! See burrows wheeler compression

2) no.

3) no.